# Able to extract proper dtypes of a DF in Local but if i tried the same in GCP Dataproc (Source input file) facing the issue

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pyspark

Am able to extract the datatypes of the DF (DF created from a CSV file).

When i tried the same in dataproc getting all datatypes as "string". 
can i get any help here:

Code which worked in Local Machine for me.

```
df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("Path")

colList=df.columns

d=df.dtypes
print(d)

b=[]
for x in d:
    b.append(x[1])
print(b)

df1=sc.parallelize([b]).toDF(colList)
c=df1.show()
print(c)
```

Required Output and expected is same

```
UNIFICATION_ID|EMPLID|ACAD_CAREER|STDNT_CAR_NBR|ADM_APPL_NBR|
+--------------+------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|        string|string|     string|          int|         int|     
+--------------+------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Output iam getting if i run the same code in Google Dataproc.

```
UNIFICATION_ID|EMPLID|ACAD_CAREER|STDNT_CAR_NBR|ADM_APPL_NBR|
+--------------+------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|        string|string|     string|     string  |    string  |     
+--------------+------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to reproduce your issue, and the problem might be residing within the CSV format.

I tried to reproduce the issue with the next CSV sample that I could found with different types called [Sample insurance portfolio](https://support.spatialkey.com/spatialkey-sample-csv-data/) both in Cloud Shell and within Dataproc and your code seems to be fine.

I attached the result of running the job via Dataproc here:

[image: All types seems to be fine when running your code as a job within Dataproc as a PySpark job]

Nonetheless, I will suggest you to take a look at the CSV format that it is upload in your Cloud Storage Bucket.

Also you can try to run the job with the CSV sample that I provide you with, in order to see if it is really a problem with Dataproc, or with your CSV format.

I hope this helps.